# Could not find a part of the path 'c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\~\INSA.cfg'

Tags: windows

Server Error in '/' Application.

Could not find a part of the path 'c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\~\INSA.cfg'. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\~\INSA.cfg'.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\~\INSA.cfg'.]
   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) +271
   System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost) +1217
   System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost) +144
   System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(String path, Encoding encoding, Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean checkHost) +174
   System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(String path) +53
   INSA.Web.GBK.GBKManager.GetGBKConnectionString(String fileName) +54
   INSA.Web.GBK.GBKManager.CreateGBKConnection(String fileName, Boolean crcProvided) +10
   PMS.Global.Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e) +71

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not find a part of the path 'c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\~\INSA.cfg'.]
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +520
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +176
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +165
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +267
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +341

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not find a part of the path 'c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\~\INSA.cfg'.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +523
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +107
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +688

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.3429.0

Comment: NB: the file in that directory not found

Comment: Some code here:-  void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Code that  runs  on application  startup 
            Lic.SkipCheckLic = true;
            SA.InitializeDataBase("INSA.cfg");
            // Include  your  custome  codes here 
        }

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: In this directory :- c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\   the file INSA.cfg is not visible because of that the file could not find and how to visible in this directory?